# Using .NET string functions in where clause of LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

How can I use .NET frameworks string functions in LINQ query like this?

```
var accounts = from a in orgContext.CreateQuery("account")
                      where a["telephone1"].ToString().Replace("-","") == "1234567890"
                      orderby a["name"]
                      select new { id = a["accountid"], name = a["name"], telephone1 = a["telephone1"]};
```

This is ending up with error:

`Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.`

**UPDATE**
I tried this LINQ query against a test db in SQL Server after genearting entity classes and it returns the result successfully:

```
from Account in db.Account
where Account.Telephone1.Replace("-", "").Substring(Account.Telephone1.Replace("-", "").Length - 10, 10) == "1234567890"
select new {
  Account.AccountId,
  Account.Name,
  Account.Telephone1
}
```

But as I am LINQ querying in Dynamics CRM using late bound entities as shown in the first code sample (with no entity classes in the project), the application ended up with a run-time error.

PS: I can't use early bound entities because this may break the solution when customers will add any attribute to the Dynamics CRM entity.

Comment: If this LINQ query is being converted to SQL as it appears then you need to make sure your .NET functions are convertible to SQL functions.  If you were using just linq-to-objects then what you have here would work.

Comment: @JNYRanger Does .Replace() .NET function is convertible to T-SQL's replace() function or not?

Comment: I do not believe so.  You should use the static methods in the [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: However, you can do conversions prior to the Linq-to-Entities query, but that will add some additional time.

Comment: @JNYRanger But I am unable to find .Replace() t-sql equivalent in SqlFunctions class.

Comment: Then you cannot use it in a linq-to-entity query.  You'll need to do a transformation of the string first then write your query using the transformed elements.

Comment: @JNYRanger Thanks for your suggestion. Can you provide a sample for this? How could I do/adjust the string transformation code in my sample?

Comment: I can, but I need more info.  What are you actually matching on?  The telephone number?  How is this match variable located/stored?

Comment: Yes against a telephone number that is stored in a CRM database.

Comment: Move to chat I'll explain

Comment: Your understanding of EarlyBound entities is incorrect.  You can use early bound entities as much as you like, and customers can add whatever attributes they'd like as well.  They only thing they couldn't do is remove one of the attributes you're referencing, and in that case it'll fail if it's early or late bound.  So save yourself the trouble and use earlybound!  (not that it helps solve this problem in any way)

Comment: @Daryl Thanks. I didn't test this myself but read this from Dynamics CRM 2013 SDK `... the code generation tool (CrmSvcUtil) creates early-bound entity classes that you can use to access business data in Microsoft Dynamics CRM. These classes include one class for each entity in your installation, including custom entities. Each time you make customizations to your system, you must regenerate these classes.` If you are right then this statement seems misguiding?

Comment: It is misleading but not misguiding.  You obviously have to regenerate the classes to reference something you just added to CRM.  But if you never use it, it'll work just fine.  The early bound is just a wrapper around the late bound entity.

Comment: @Daryl Well I tried `.Where(e => e.Telephone1.Replace("-", "") == "0123456789")` with early bound entities, but it ended up with `Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method.` at run-time. The apparent cause of this is what @Nicknow pointed `Queries are built using standard language, but internally uses QueryExpression so is limited to the features of QueryExpression.`

Comment: Yes, my first post said it won't solve your current problem, and it won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this. The Dynamics CRM LINQ Provider does not support this capability because `QueryExpression` does not support this search.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334607.aspx

> Queries are built using standard language, but internally uses
>   QueryExpression so is limited to the features of QueryExpression.

To perform this search you need to have a cleaned value in CRM. I've had this issues doing TAPI (telephone) integration before. The solution was to create a plugin on Create/Update that did the replace on phone number and put the value in a different field (i.e., "new_cleanphonenumber") which could then be searched.

You can use the same clean-up code to write a simple command line utility to go through and update all the existing values.

Comment: Thanks Nicknow. I had this idea in my mind as a last option :). But that would be not an ideal solution.

Comment: Well, just for my clarification, Dynamics CRM LINQ Provider is based on QueryExpression really? Can you provide some reading on this to clarify my understanding.

Comment: Updated my answer with the SDK reference and the quote.

Comment: Is there any update regarding the use of string manipulation functions in QueryExpressions/LINQ queries?

Comment: @KhadimAli - No changes to date, I wouldn't expect any to be coming. For such a query to be of value the logic would have to be executed in the SQL query itself which would open up more potential for bad code to overload the server. This is opposite of the product goal, at this point.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the SqlFunctions.StringConvert Method.

This is the msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx

```
var accounts = from a in orgContext.CreateQuery("account")
                                  where SqlFunctions.StringConvert(a["telephone1"]).Replace("-","") == "1234567890"
                                  orderby a["name"]
                                  select new { id = a["accountid"], name = a["name"], telephone1 = a["telephone1"] };
```

Comment: AS StringConvert doucmentation says `Returns character data converted from numeric data.` it requires numeric value as a parameter. In my case a["xxxx"] is an entity propery that is not numeric type.

Comment: returns error `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double?)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: What is the database type of this column ?

Comment: @Ali.NET the SqlFunctions provides you with a number of functions which are used based on the database type

Comment: Can you please modify the sample code accordingly. I tried to find the one but failed.

Comment: why you call ToString() if it is the column type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71804/discussion-between-med-amine-touil-and-ali-net).

Answer (score 1):

This portion of your query: `a["telephone1"].ToString().Replace("-","")` cannot be converted into a valid SQL statement or whatever is the underlying domain language.  When using linq-to-entities your queries need to be expressed in the SQL flavor of your underlying database or the domain language of the entity if not SQL based.  When using linq-to-objects, this is not the case, and your query would be valid.

You can use the static methods in [SqlFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) within a linq-to-entity query, but as you have already noticed you don't really have many options for string manipulations.  Also, your underlying entity is dynamics-crm so unless you're connecting directly to the SQL database you probably can't use SQL statements anyway.

In your case you would need to transform the telephone string to the proper format prior using it in the query.  However, I see that you're comparing to a constant string of `"1234567890"`, so instead of removing dashes from the dynamic object, put the dashes into your constant string such as `"123-456-7890`" assuming this is a telephone number as your query suggests.

Comment: The point in this conversion of db values to remove extra characters is that whatever format users enter in telephone field should be converted to a clean number that could be compared against a given number. Ofcourse the number wouldn't be a constant. I just used constant to make an example.

Comment: @Ali.NET I kind of figured that, but the point is that if you have a portion of your query that's static within the query it can be done outside of it.  However, Nicknow's answer kind of sounds like your best bet if your data isn't in a normalized format.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you where you said `if you have a portion of your query that's static within the query it can be done outside of it`

Comment: Yeah I'm having a bit of trouble putting it into the right words.  Can you post what you're actually matching on?  I'll try to make up an example.